# Convert existing JAR to OSGi-bundle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a JAR file that I need to convert to an OSGi bundle. 
I do not have the original source code for the JAR file.

I tried to use the answers from: [How to create OSGi bundle from jar library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594024/how-to-create-osgi-bundle-from-jar-library)

However, they are pretty outdated.

**Edit:** I need to convert several, but a fixed number of jars.

Comment: Is there a method that does not involve Eclipse?

Comment: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Migration

Comment: This [blog](http://skysailserver.blogspot.de/2013/10/converting-ordinary-jar-into-osgi.html) is about creating the bundle _without_ involving Eclipse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1** - use *bnd-platform* to build your OSGi bundles when expecting frequent additions/updates of Jars, or when you can retrieve your dependencies from Maven repositories

We use [bnd-platform](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform) (I am also the author) to manage third party dependencies and create OSGi bundles from them. You can use it with both dependencies retrieved from Maven repositories and local Jars (see the [README](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform#local-dependencies)). If you regularly add or update your dependencies I would suggest that you try *bnd-platform*. It's a plugin for Gradle, you can easily start with [this template](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal) - just add your Jar files and provide the configuration as described in the project README (bundle symbolic names, versions) and run `gradlew bundles`.

**Option 2** - use *bnd* to build your OSGi bundles when you do it once or additions/updates are seldom

If you only do this process once or seldom, a simple way to create an OSGi bundle from an existing Jar is to directly use [bnd on the command line](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/CommandLine). The only thing you need is Java and the bnd jar. You can use `wrap` to try to automatically wrap a jar or create a `.bnd` file with [instructions for bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format) (e.g. to only export specific packages).

Example .bnd file:

```
-classpath: lib/trove-2.0.4.jar
-output: gnu.trove-2.0.4.jar
Export-Package: *;-split-package:=merge-last;-noimport:=true
Import-Package: *
Bundle-Version: 2.0.4
Bundle-Name: GNU Trove Collections Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: gnu.trove
```

Example call:

```
java -jar <path to bnd>.jar trove-2.0.4.bnd
```

The bnd Jar download is no longer offered directly through the web site, a good  alternative is to [download it from Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22biz.aQute.bnd%22%20AND%20a%3A%22bnd%22).

Comment: Just adding this piece of information - you have to add the main jar with all its dependencies (the list separated by comma) in the -classpath entry. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The [Eclipse Bundle Recipe](https://github.com/eclipse/ebr) project provides a Maven based approach for adding OSGi meta data to JARs consumed from a Maven repository. Despite the name it doesn't use Eclipse.

At its core, it uses the [bnd tool](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd). This tool is like a swiss army knife. It analyzes jars and class files and properly calculate package import and exports. You should use bnd for converting proprietary jars yourself. It's [available in Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/biz.aQute.bnd/bnd).

Comment: this won't work if you share this dependency across bundles - you will get a classloader conflict

Comment: @zacheusz, Please open a _new_ question with the specific problem you are facing. It looks like you are running into an issue with the specific library. In general, bundles created by processing JARs with **bnd** work very well. However, some libraries require additional steps to become good OSGi citizens.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Maven then you can use the Maven Bundle Plugin to inline or embed dependencies in a OSGi bundle:

http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies

Comment: Hi, I wonder what if the jar also has dpenendencies of jar file? I tried maven-bundle-plugin to transform jar A to a bundle. However, when I check the MANIFEST.MF of the generated bundle, I saw in the Import-Package, there are a lot of jar packages which needs to be imported. I think this is a loop. I need to first transfrom jar A to a bundle, then I need to transform its jar dependencies to bundles, then dependencies of dependencies...... As long as there is a jar package in the Import-Package, I can not use bndrun to test this bundle......

Answer (score 0):

or just use osgi:install with wrap option as below.

```
osgi:install wrap:file:/u01/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
```

this will deploy the jar file as bundle and you can get the bundle under "$fuse_home/data/cache/bundle{id}/version0.0" folder.

Comment: Just as a side note: To make this work you need to install pax url wrap.