# OSGi dependency for org.beanio not resolving

Tags: maven, osgi, jbossfuse, fuseesb, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm trying to `OSGify` my projects.

I'm using `Fuse jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084`, and if I look at `osgi:headers` for the package, I get the red error `org.beanio`.

```
Import-Package =
    com.thoughtworks.xstream;version="[1.4,2)",
    javax.activation,
    javax.mail;version="[1.4,2)",
    javax.mail.internet;version="[1.4,2)",
    javax.xml.bind,
    org.apache.activemq.camel.component,
    org.apache.camel;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.camel.builder;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.fixed,
    org.apache.camel.spring.spi;version="[2.15,3)",
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor;version="[3.0,4)",
    org.apache.log4j;version="[1.2,2)",
    org.beanio;version="[2.1,3)",
    (others)
```

Error:

> missing requirement osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.beanio)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))

I'm not explicitly importing `beanio` myself: it gets it from the `org.jboss.fuse.bom` for this Fuse.  The `camel-beanio version` is `2.15.1.redhat-621084` and that uses `org.beanio v2.1.0`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-beanio</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I've grep searched the `osgi:classes` and nothing is using v3.0. Also, v3.0 doesn't even exist. So, I don't know where it's getting that "[2.1,3)" from.

I worked out how to specify 2.1.0, but it then just complains that it can't find 2.1.0.

So what do I do?  Nothing is exporting 2.1.0.  But I can't get rid of it from Import-Package because * includes it after searching the code.

Comment: you seem to be misunderstanding the error message. It says it requires `org.beanio` version >= 2.1.0 and NOT >= 3.0.0... the syntax `[2.1,3)` means 2.1 inclusive, up to 3 exclusive.

Comment: You can install camel-beanio first by running `install:feature camel-beanio` in the fuse shell. And you should always use the same version in your project as Fuse uses.

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself: *"The camel-beanio version is 2.15.1.redhat-621084 and that uses org.beanio v2.1.0"*.

You just need this in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.beanio</groupId>
    <artifactId>beanio</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is in Maven Central so it should work.

As I mentioned in a comment, the error message you got tells you you need the package `org.beanio` with version >= 2.1.0 and NOT >= 3.0.

The above dependency provides this package, as you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.beanio/beanio/2.1.0).

However, this does not seem to be a OSGi bundle... so you'll have to [wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494485/convert-existing-jar-to-osgi-bundle).

Comment: I added that exact dependency.  Doesn't fix it.  I understand that it's looking for >v2.1.0... as I said, 3.0 doesn't even exist.  I have to wrap it?  Ah I see Claus's comment... will give that a go.

Comment: So, the features:install worked.  Adding the dependency did not work though.

Comment: So your framework is wrapping the jar for you... If you wrapped it yourself using Bnd, Pax::wrap or the osgi-run gradle plugin, it would work as well.

Comment: I added a link to a SO question on how to wrap jars into OSGi bundles. For anyone using Gradle, just use [osgi-run](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/osgi-run#wrapping-non-bundles-flat-jars) and it will wrap the jar automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Include the dependency in `features.xml` as below:

```
<bundle>mvn:org.beanio/beanio/${version}</bundle>
```

Then, type `features:refreshurl` command and install the bundle