# Is it required to import transitive dependencies as bundles to KURA

Tags: java, osgi, kura

I am very new to OSGI and KURA. I am tackling with a problem since yesterday and I did not understand its reason.

Please, tell me if my way is wrong.

I am using `dropbox-core-sdk` (version 3.0.0) in my project. I have downloaded its jar and also, I have researched that it has a dependency on `jackson-core` (version 2.7.4). I have also downloaded its jar and I have created a bundle with `dropbox-core-sdk.jar` and `jackson-core.jar`.

Firstly, I have imported the dependencies (bundle with dropbox and jackson) and then imported my own project.

When I start my project, it throws the following exception;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.prepRequest(StandardHttpRequestor.java:196)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:70)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:28)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostRaw(DbxRequestUtil.java:232)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2$1.execute(DbxRawClientV2.java:100)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.executeRetriable(DbxRawClientV2.java:256)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:97)
    at com.dropbox.core.v2.users.DbxUserUsersRequests.getCurrentAccount(DbxUserUsersRequests.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi.DropBoxTransfer.<init>(DropBoxTransfer.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi.DropBoxUpdateJob.execute(DropBoxUpdateJob.java:20)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

I have two related questions;

1. When we create a bundle from a public api, should this bundle contain the transitive dependencies of the public api?
2. Even if I supplied the Dropbox api with its transitive dependencies, why threw the program such an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically `NoClassDefFoundError` happens when a bundle loads a class that is not present in the bundle and there is not `Import-Package` statement for the package of the class.

When creating bundles make sure you use a bnd to auto create the Manifest with suitable `Import-Package` and `Export-Package` instructions.

I would always use the build to create a bundle from a jar. As I use maven I would use a maven plugin. [See this question for some possible ways to create bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494485/convert-existing-jar-to-osgi-bundle).

Comment: When I am creating bundle, I am using eclipse file -> new -> other -> Plug-in From Existing JAR Archieves. Is it not a good way to create bundle?

Comment: and additionally, how would I know that which package should I import from "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection" this statement?

Comment: The package you need to import is "javax.net.ssl". The eclipse pde support sucks. I recommend to build the bundle using a maven build. See answer for options to create a bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. After your tip, I started to use bnd command line. What I still do not understand that Should I include the transitive dependencies when I am converting jars into bundle with bnd?

Comment: It depends on how you want to do your deployment. If your dependencies are bundles then you typically do not want to embed them. Likewise you can create one bundle per dependency or one bundle including all transitive  deps... but better do not mix the two approaches too much.